# CSS: Increase parent width if height of p overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have an image which is 100% of the window. Inside I have an absolutely positioned div (with the class `caption`) which displays a header and some text. This caption has a `min-width` of 36%. My website if fully responsive.

I am using media queries to reposition the caption on tablets and mobiles. However, sometimes the text inside the `item` is too large - the height of the caption is greater than the image.

I am using the following code to fix this using javascript, but it feels a big buggy (and it does not work when the user resizes the browser):

```
window.onload = function(){
  setWidth();
};

var count = 0;
function setWidth() {
    $('.item').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).find('.caption')[0].scrollHeight >  $(this).height() && count <= 100) {
            $(this).find('.caption').css('width', $(this).find('.caption').width() + 10);
            count++;
            setWidth();
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way I could achieve the same effect using just css. Something where `max-height` on the `caption` is 100%, the `min-width` is 36% and the width will change accordingly as the height of the caption changes.

Comment: to work your code when resize the browser you have to use `window.onresize` event. To give you a better solution can you create a sample in jsfiddle.net and share with us...

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to see whether CSS is feasible without markup for your example. As for the JavaScript, you want to attach your `resize` function to the `window.onresize` event, this will call whenever the window is resized.

[See example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ja9tv/)

```
window.onresize = updateDimensions;

function updateDimensions(e) {
    document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = window.innerWidth;
    document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = window.innerHeight;
}

updateDimensions();
```